# How to download files in webView?

Tags: android, webview

There are two ways to download files in a webView-

**1) download via webview**

```
// download manager
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
            long contentLength) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                Uri.parse(url));
        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition,
                mimeType));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                        url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
// download manager
```

**2) open app chooser to download via 3rd party apps-**

```
 // download via...
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
            long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "don't choose our app as it can't handle download intents, i have posted a question on stackoverflow though.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
// download via..
```

But how do i make both of them work together? I want my app to show a dialog which gives you two options of either downloading within the app or via 3rd part app.

Comment: please change your question if you can, because you are asking horribly wrong you want an alert dialog and you are asking for download files from webview so it makes pretty confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this snippet

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("How you want to download this file?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Use webView",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id){

                    //your code here for download manager
                    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onDownloadStart(String url,String userAgent,
                                                    String contentDisposition,String mimeType,
                                                    long contentLength){
                            DownloadManager.Request request=new DownloadManager.Request(
                                    Uri.parse(url));
                            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                            String cookies= CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                            request.addRequestHeader("cookie",cookies);
                            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent",userAgent);
                            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,
                                    mimeType));
                            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,URLUtil.guessFileName(
                                            url,contentDisposition,mimeType));
                            DownloadManager dm=(DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                            dm.enqueue(request);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Downloading File",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();} });
                    dismiss();}})
            .setNegativeButton("3rd Party App",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id){

                    // download via...
                    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener(){

                        public void onDownloadStart(String url,String userAgent,
                                                    String contentDisposition,String mimetype,
                                                    long contentLength){
                            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                            startActivity(i);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"don't choose our app as it can't handle download intents, i have posted a question on stackoverflow though.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }});dialog.cancel();} });
    AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

This is snippet i have added that will show you two options like you want just put your logic in button's on click method.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("How you want to download?")
   .setCancelable(false)
   .setPositiveButton("By web", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //use logic of downloading with web view here
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("Use third party tool", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //use logic of third party tool here
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```